# Inclusion between Bourgain spaces $X^{s,b}$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

The Bourgain space is $X^{s,b} := X^{s,b}(\mathbb R \times \mathbb{T}^3)$ is the completion of $C^\infty (\mathbb R; H^s(\mathbb{T}^3))$ under the norm

$$\| u\|_{X^{s,b}}:= \|e^{- i t \triangle u(t,x)}\|_{H_t^b (\mathbb{R}; H_x^s(\mathbb{T}^3))}\\ =\left(\sum_{\xi \in \mathbb{Z}^3} \int_\mathbb{R} <\tau+\sum_{j=1}^3 \theta_j \xi^2_j>^{2b} <\xi>^{2s} |\hat{u}(\tau,\xi)|^2 d\tau \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$

I am trying to prove the following:

1- For $s_1 \leq s_2$ and $b_1 \leq b_2$, $X^{s_2,b_2} \hookrightarrow X^{s_1,b_2}$.

2- For $b > 1/2$, $X^{0,b} \hookrightarrow C_t L_x^2$.

3- $X^{0,1/4} \hookrightarrow L_t^4 L_x^2$

I am new to mixed norms. However, I solved the first point by, as in the comments, taking the bounded remaining term out. I am confused with the second and third points? Any help.

Comment: what do you mean by got another square? It should follow just by taking $L^\infty$ of the remaining $1+|\xi|^2$ power. Oh I see, you are in particular claiming that $\|f\|_{H^1} \le \|f\|_{L^2}$. Its the reverse inequality that is true.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Now I am dealing with mixed, Bourgain, norm where $x \in \mathbb T ^3$ is the procedure the same?

Comment: I don’t know because I don’t work on dispersive equations. Can you include the definition in your question?

Comment: @CalvinKhor I edited the question. I showed what I want to prove.

Comment: I am confused with your question. Firstly, if $s \leq t$, then $\| f \|_{H^s} \leq \| f \|_{H^t}$. You wrote down the opposite inequality. Secondly, with the definition of Sobolev norms you are using this inequality is obvious because $(1+|\xi|^2)^s \leq (1+|\xi|^2)^t$. Secondly, you mention some other spaces $X^{s,b}$ after the word "Edit", but it's unclear what does this part have to do with the original question.

Comment: @Blazej Sorry for the typos. My question is the last part. I wanted to solve it myself but I could not, so I posted it. What is $C_t$?

Comment: Please consider editing your question so that it is easier for people to understand what you meant.

Comment: @Blazej I edited it.